# Comparing a local directory with specific Github branch

Tags: git, github

My website code is at /home/www.  Currently this is not a git repository.

I have a repo on Github called wordpress with a develop branch.  Changes have been made on wordpress/develop branch and I'd like to compare them to my files in /home/www.  Once I see the changes, I'd like to then pull them down from wordpress/develop into my /home/www folder.

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, make your local codes a git repository.

```
cd /home/www
git init
git add -A
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

Then, add a remote reference to the github repository, and fetch it to local.

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:michaeluser/wordpress.git
git fetch origin develop
```

At last, you can compare it to the local branch.

```
git diff master origin/develop
```

If you find any differences, you want to merge to local.

```
git merge origin/develop
```

Comment: thank you but I keep getting this error

fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/develop': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Answer (score 0):

`git diff master origin/develop` is how you'd compare your branch to the remote one.

If you don't have a remote, create one:

```
git remote add origin [url]
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that's going to work since I haven't even specified the git location git@github.com:michaeluser/wordpress.git

Answer (score 0):

I landed here trying to achieve the same. But I wanted to commit the changes made in the directory to the origin later.

To just connect your local files to the origin HEAD you have to do the following

```
git init
git add origin your_url
git reset --soft origin master
git status
```

I had to do an

```
git add .
```

to see the modified files. It showed me a lot of deletions and added files.

Your local git is now on the HEAD state of the origin master, with all commits copied. Now use all the "normal" git commands and commit or revert the changes.